# Using systemd to start an application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, systemctl

I want to create a linux service to start another application. For simplicity's sake let's just say it's Firefox.

System Info:

```
➜  ~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I've created a bash script to run firefox:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentTime=$(date +"%I:%M:%S")
echo "My Test: Starting Firefox @ $currentTime"
firefox &
```

I've created a .service file for systemd

```
[Unit]
Description=My Test Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
SyslogIdentifier=mytest
ExecStart=/home/myuser/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've placed the .service file in `/etc/systemd/system` and enabled/started it using these commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable mytest.service
sudo systemctl start mytest
```

Here's the output from `sudo systemctl status mytest`

```
● mytest.service - My Test Service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mytest.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-02-11 16:11:59 CST; 6s ago
Process: 4131 ExecStart=/home/myuser/linux-scripts/test.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 4131 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Feb 11 16:11:59 NUC5i3RYH systemd[1]: Started My Test Service.
Feb 11 16:11:59 NUC5i3RYH mytest[4131]: My Test: Starting firefox @ 04:11:59
```

The script appears to run but Firefox does not start. If I run the bash script directly Firefox opens up immediately. Can anyone see something I'm doing wrong here? I'm new to linux and its utilities so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `systemd` does not want the new service to background itself unless you tell it otherwise. Try changing `firefox &` to just `firefox`. Also,do you have your X display open so that `systemd` has access?

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to do this as a _system-wide_ service instead of a _per-user_ service?

Comment: Would making it a per-user service solve my problem? @JdeBP

Comment: I updated my script to just be `firefox`. I do not have my X display open and I believe that's why I'm now seeing the error `Error: No DISPLAY environment variable specified`. Would I set that inside the .service file? @doneal24

Comment: I made it a per-user service and everything worked. To answer your question @JdeBP like I said, I'm new to linux so it's mostly just my own ignorance

Comment: @SethHarris it would be helpful for others if you wrote up a brief answer to your own question that shows how you solved the problem :)